# mypy: Signature of "__setitem__" incompatible with supertype "list"

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to use a specialised subclass of List to create a TokenList that is backed by a regular list, but also contains a metadata dict with key/values. Everything works great, until I wanted to add types to this, and now I'm getting this error:

```
error: Signature of "__setitem__" incompatible with supertype "list"
```

... and the error is the first overload below:

```py
import typing as T

class Token(dict):
    ...

class TokenList(T.List[Token]):
    ...

    @T.overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: int, tokens: T.Union[dict, Token]) -> None: ...  # noqa, pragma: no cover

    @T.overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: slice, tokens: T.Union[T.Iterable[T.Union[dict, Token]], 'TokenList']) -> None: ...  # noqa, pragma: no cover

    def __setitem__(self, key, tokens):  # noqa: F811
        if isinstance(key, int):
            token = tokens
            token = self._dict_to_token_and_set_defaults(token)
            super(TokenList, self).__setitem__(key, token)
        else:
            tokens = [self._dict_to_token_and_set_defaults(token) for token in tokens]
            super(TokenList, self).__setitem__(key, tokens)
```

I've tried to find the type defintition for `list` to compare it to mine, but hasn't been able to find it.

**Except for ignoring this error and going on with my life, is there any way around this? Any pointers appreciated.**

(I'm using mypy 0.910 and Python 3.9.1 if that matters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out the static type of any object with [`reveal_type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#reveal-type). So trying:

```
reveal_type(list.__setitem__)
```

Gives you:

```
reveal_type.py:2: note: Revealed type is "Overload(def [_T] (builtins.list[_T`1], typing_extensions.SupportsIndex, _T`1), def [_T] (builtins.list[_T`1], builtins.slice, typing.Iterable[_T`1]))"
```

The problem with your original code is that lists can be indexed by more than just `int`s and `slice`s: they support any object that can be coerced into integers with [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__index__) as well.

So that means you need to make two changes: import `typing_extensions` and replace `int` with `typing_extensions.SupportsIndex`.

```
import typing_extensions as TE

...

def __setitem__(self, key: TE.SupportsIndex, tokens: T.Union[dict, Token]) -> None: ...  # noqa, pragma: no cover
```

Also, that means that your implementation isn't quite correct, since non-integer non-slice indexes will be treated as slice indexes. I would write it as follows:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, tokens):  # noqa: F811
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        tokens = [self._dict_to_token_and_set_defaults(token) for token in tokens]
    else:
        tokens = self._dict_to_token_and_set_defaults(tokens)
    super().__setitem__(key, tokens)
```

Comment: This is one of the best answers I’ve seen, well researched and also brief and to the point. I’m honored to have it be the reply to my question.